# How to move 2 elements from head into given position in vector

Tags: c++, vector, memmove

I want to move the first 2 elements to given position in vector, the result is not right by using `memmove` in following code:

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 0};
memmove(&(v[3]), &(v[0]), 2);
```

The result by doing so is `1, 2, 3, 1, 0`, while the expectation is `1, 2, 3, 1, 2`. How can I achieve my job?

Comment: `memmove` is for moving *bytes*, not objects. You are moving 2 bytes. An `int` is (usually) 4 bytes.

Comment: @BoBTFish So I should use 2 * sizeof(int) instead of 2 as the third parameter in memove, am I right?

Comment: No, you should not use `memmove` to move objects. Consider `std::copy`, but look at the other standard algorithms too.

Comment: @BoBTFish But it works by using `2 * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: By the way, I think the correct term for what you want to achieve is "to copy".

Comment: @vinllen "It works" and "it is a good idea" are 2 very different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memmove` copies bytes, not arbitrary objects (like `int`). So you would need to calculate the correct byte count with `2 * sizeof(int)`.

But a better way is to use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
std::copy_n(v.begin(), 2, v.begin() + 3);
```

Comment: Yes, it's right. It looks like `memmove` using another temporary memory to store the source data which is inefficient

Comment: @vinllen In practice, no. Check out the "notes" section here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove.

Comment: I still have a question, this post(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_n/) says "If the ranges overlap, some of the elements in the range pointed by result may have undefined but valid values." What's the meaning of "undefined but valid" ? The function template seems it not supports overlapped ranges

Comment: @vinllen The standard doesn't specify the order in which elements are copied. Thus, the result of the operation is implementation-dependent for overlapping ranges.